# How to parse response [object object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The request is being sent from onclick of `href=url`. When this url is hit, I am returning data from server to client as a query string.

```
res.redirect("/#blog_post_details/?dataUrl="+response[0].attributes);
```

And when I print using:

```
var posts = DataMixin.getParameterByName(dataUrl);
console.log('posts', posts); //I get [Object, Object]
```

I also tried with `JSON.Stringify`:
`console.log('posts', JSON.Stringify(posts));` 
which prints the same with quotes `"[Object,Object]"`

Function to return query string:

```
getParameterByName: function (name, url) {
    if (!url) {
      url = window.location.href;
    }
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

However, I am able to print response data on server:

```
{ created_at: '4/3/2017, 1:23:28 AM',
  details: 'jjj',
  id: 136,
  post_id: '1491162808010',
  title: 'Basic Syntax and Tag declaration',
  url: 'basic_syntax_and_tag_declaration',
  userImage: 'assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png',
  username: 'k999@gmail.com' }
```

Note: I am using expressjs with nodejs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[Object, Object]` is the value you are **sending**. Parsing it won't do any good, there is nothing useful to parse.

You need to fix how you are sending the data.

Encoding it as JSON is one approach:

```
var values = response[0].attributes;
var json_values = JSON.stringify(values);
var url_safe_json_values = encodeURIComponent(json_values);
res.redirect("/#blog_post_details/?dataUrl=" + url_safe_json_values
```

**then** you parse the JSON (with `JSON.parse` not `JSON.stringify` (which does the opposite of parsing!)) at the other end.

Comment: Encoding the response worked but I want to know why did this happen? What happens during data transfer without encoding?

Comment: You took a string and used the `+` operator with an object on the right hand side. That implicitly calls `toString()` on the object. That returns the string `"[object Object]"`

Comment: Okay now I understand. Thank you